# Spring Cloud Stream Error Handling using external destination

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have been reading the spring-cloud-stream documentation, specifically [error handling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Fishtown.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-overview-error-handling):

```
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT) // destination name 'input.myGroup'
public void handle(Person value) {
    throw new RuntimeException("BOOM!");
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT + ".myGroup.errors") //channel name 'input.myGroup.errors'
public void error(Message<?> message) {
    System.out.println("Handling ERROR: " + message);
}
```

Regarding to what the documentation says about it, when you want to catch the errors, you might want to use `@ServiceActivator`. This does not have an associated external destination.

> The use of @StreamListener annotation is intended specifically to
>   define bindings that bridge internal channels and external
>   destinations. Given that the destination specific error channel does
>   NOT have an associated external destination, such channel is a
>   prerogative of Spring Integration (SI). This means that the handler
>   for such destination must be defined using one of the SI handler
>   annotations (i.e., @ServiceActivator, @Transformer etc.).

I have also followed this whole thread about [error channel creation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1338), where it confirms that having a `@ServiceActivator` annotation will not create an external destination to propagate the errors.

I have a use case where an external listener process will be consuming the errors published into a particular Kafka error-topic. Based on this, I have the following questions,

1. What does specifically do `@ServiceActivator` or wthat is the feature that this particular annotation provide?
2. What would be a good approach to propagate the errors to an external destination? (Let's say for example, a Kafka topic).
3. Is publishing the error into an external destination in order to be consumed later on a good pattern ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ServiceActivator would be specifically for internal error handling (i.e., by the same application). For cases where you want errors to be sent to a Kafka topic so they can be consumed by an external consumer you should use the DLQ. You can find more details here https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#kafka-dlq-processing

Please let us know if you still have more questions